# Reviews on Google Assistant application

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I built an app for Google Assistant using actions on Google. I've asked my friends to rate it. They rated it, but it's only visible to them. 
What is the reason ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

If you assistant is in Alpha or Beta, Google doesn't count that reviews.

> Note: Users cannot rate your Action in the Google Assistant app if
>   they are using alpha or beta versions. Instead, you should provide
>   testers with a way to provide feedback by email, via a website, in a
>   message forum, or through another suitable mechanism.

Source: https://developers.google.com/actions/deploy/release-environments#get-feedback

Comment: that is not the problem here . thanks for your suggestion